Output from stage not visible in condition of next stage
I am developing Terraform pipeline and i want to set a variable in a stage and then, output it so i can use it in another stage.
So this is my code that works:
stages:
- stage: Terraform_Plan
  displayName: Plan
  jobs:
  - job: Terraform_Plan
    displayName: Plan 

    steps:
    
    - powershell: |
        # made it shorter to get a point, that variable set here is not 
        # respected in next stage
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyTfChanges;isOutput=true]false"

      displayName: Detect any Terraform changes

And in another stage, i want to use it from condition:
 stage: Terraform_Apply
  displayName: Apply
  jobs:
  - deployment: Apply
    environment: dev
    displayName: Apply Terraform
    condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), eq('true', 'true'), eq(dependencies.Terraform_Plan.outputs['Terraform_Plan.anyTfChanges'], 'true')))

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

but it looks like that variable is not respected at all because Apply stage runs all the time, even when i set anyTfChanges variable to false
Any ideas how to make it works? I use windows agents

From your YAML sample, you need to pass the variable between stages. Refer to this doc: Use outputs in a different stage
You can try to use the following sample:
stages:
- stage: Terraform_Plan
  displayName: Plan
  jobs:
  - job: Terraform_Plan
    displayName: Plan 

    steps:
    
    - powershell: |
        # made it shorter to get a point, that variable set here is not 
        # respected in next stage
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyTfChanges;isOutput=true]false"

      displayName: Detect any Terraform changes
      name: test
- stage: Terraform_Apply
  displayName: Apply
  dependsOn: Terraform_Plan
  variables:
     varFromA: $[ stageDependencies.Terraform_Plan.Terraform_Plan.outputs['test.anyTfChanges'] ]
  jobs:
  - deployment: Apply
    environment: dev
    displayName: Apply Terraform
    condition: and(succeeded(), and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), eq('true', 'true'), eq(variables['varFromA'], 'true')))
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo "1"

You also need to change the OR operator to And in the condition.
The OR operator means that one of the judgments pass will run the stage. The eq('true', 'true') will always pass.
In this case, the stage will be run only when all three judgments are satisfied.
Result:


Adding variable to stage made it, thanks
